# Wordpress tinyMCE window manager upload button not adding url to text field

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have a button added to the WYSIWYG that opens a popup with fields to fill in. With those fields I am trying to add another button that will choose a file from the media library and insert the link/url in a text field. I have the button working and it opens the media library, but when I select a file, nothing gets inserted into the text field.

If I add an alert for json.url after the media selection it will alert me of the file link, So I know that it is getting the url from the file. However, I can't get it into the text field.

Here is the piece of code from my `editor_plugin.js` file:

```
{
    type: 'textbox',
    name: 'myfile',
    label: 'My File',
    id: 'my-file',
    value: ''
},{
    type: 'button',
    name: 'select-file',
    text: 'Upload File',
    onclick: function() {
        window.mb = window.mb || {};

        window.mb.frame = wp.media({
            frame: 'post',
            state: 'insert',
            library : {
                type : 'image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        window.mb.frame.on('select', function() {
            var json = window.mb.frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            alert(json.url);
            if (0 > $.trim(json.url.length)) {
                return;
            }

            $('#my-file').val(json.url);
        });

        window.mb.frame.open();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED IT!!

I removed "frame" & "state" from wp.media and changed "$" to "jQuery"

```
window.mb.frame = wp.media({

            library : {
                type : 'image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        window.mb.frame.on('select', function() {
            var json = window.mb.frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            if (0 > $.trim(json.url.length)) {
                return;
            }

            jQuery('#my-file').val(json.url);
        });
```